# How to style a scroller using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a site where on the sidebar I have some videos with a scrollbar (http://mibsoftware.us/clients/raveis), I need to figure out how style this scrollbar so it can be a different color, etc. What is best way to do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

the scroller is inside a div

Comment: Please don't bother. JavaScript-powered ersatz scroll bars are never as usable as real proper OS-provided scroll bars. Your page looks fine as-is.

Comment: @bobince. i agree, but client has no clue and wants it to look a certain way. not my loss ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [jScrollPane](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html) to style scrollbars in cross-browser fashion.
[See the basic demo here](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/basic.html)